# How to check latest version released by facebook for their sdk

Tags: ios, facebook

I have been using the fb sdk from a while,
i pod file I add

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

and then use **pod install**

and it automatically install the latest version of pod

But what I'm seeing actually **is the installed version is** [[image: installed FBSDKCoreKit version]] is 6.5.1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX5jb.png)

but the release **facebook sdk version is** [image: released fb version 9.0.1]

**is not installing a pd without to the specific version mentioned in pod file, installs the latest version automatically** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check  The **Podfile.lock** it keeps track of the resolved versions of each Pod installed.

[pod update & Pod Install](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html)

> When you run pod update PODNAME, CocoaPods will try to find an updated version of the pod PODNAME, without taking into account the version listed in Podfile.lock. It will update the pod to the latest version possible (as long as it matches the version restrictions in your Podfile).

> If you run pod update with no pod name, CocoaPods will update every pod listed in your Podfile to the latest version possible.

understand the pod install vs. pod update

> Use pod install to install new pods in your project. Even if you already have a Podfile and ran pod install before; so even if you are just adding/removing pods to a project already using CocoaPods.

> Use pod update [PODNAME] only when you want to update pods to a newer version.

so try with **pod update** instead of **pod install**